# Tab container on change event not reflecting data outside tab container

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have four tab on tab container , 
The problems is the data is not reflecting after on change event on literal control outside tab container.
please suggest

Comment: You are going to have to include some code to at least show what you have tried to do

Answer (score 0):

Tab change on Tab container can be captured in two ways:

1-One event for the whole container (click on tabContainer and Double click on "Selecting" Event).

2-One event for each tab (click on one tab and Double click on "Select" Event).

In the auto-generated event code, you can handle the behaviour of yours "literal control outside tab container", like disabling them or color them pink.

Anyhow, if a control changes with tab selection, it would be better to place it inside that tab!